# Saving hidden button state using NSUserDefaults Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Trying to save button state as hidden when navigating off the view controller.

under IBAction

```
    btnonce.hidden = YES; 

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setValue:Act1Button.hidden forKey:@"isHidden"];
```

Calling it in ViewDidLoad

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
btnonce.hidden = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"isHidden"];
```

I'm getting the error:  Implicit conversion of "BOOL" (aka signed char) to ID is disallowed with ARC

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For saving the Bool value in NSUserDefaults use this code

```
 [defaults setBool:Act1Button.hidden forKey:@"isHidden"];
```

For retrieving use this

```
btnonce.hidden = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"isHidden"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, been stuck on that for ages really appreciate it!